# Table layout problem

Tags: tables

I have a problem with a table. Since I am a day zero newbie in latex, please bare with me.

This is what I did:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Constraints/FacesX.png}
& 
dsadasd
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I added the `\hline` and `|` so I can see what is happening, but I do not need them.

This is what I get:

[image: result]

`dsadasd` is at the bottom of the cell instead of at the top. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My gut reaction is "why are you using a table", but it might be justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, that the picture is is not aligned at the top. So you may use the following approach to create a point, where the stuff can be aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\BildTop}[1]{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{0.5\textwidth}}
 \BildTop{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{TestPdf}} & dsadasd 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The macro `\BildTop` creates a vertical box (`\vbox`) with nothing in it (`\null`) in the first line and the other material e.g. your picture in the second line (`\hbox{#1}`)

[image]

Comment: a `p` column is already a vtop internally so actually you just need a `\null` (or `\vspace{0pt}` before the `\includegrapics`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `adjustbox`, which adds many facilities for managing boxes and images:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
\hline
\includegraphics[valign=t,width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
&
dsadasd
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]